# How to get a single document data from Cloud_Firestore to my variable?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have been trying to get a single data from Firestore. But I can't.

```
void _onPressed() async{
    var firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    var userData;
    firestoreInstance.collection("users").document(firebaseUser.uid).get().then((value){
      setState(){
      userData = value.data
      }
      print('Value data = ${value.data}');
    });
   print('UserData = ${userData}'); 
  }
```

Result:

```
Value data = { some data some data}
UserData = null
```

Why is my `userData` null? How do I solve this? I'm looking forward to hearing from you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get()` is asynchronous and returns immediately before the query is complete.  `then()` is also asynchronous (as well as anything that returns a Future).  Use `await` instead of `then` to pause your code until a result is available.

```
var snapshot = firestoreInstance.collection("users").document(firebaseUser.uid).get()
var userData = snapshot.data
print('UserData = ${userData}')
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to do the following:

```
void _onPressed() async{
    var userData;
    var firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    var result = await firestoreInstance.collection("users").document(firebaseUser.uid).get(); 
    setState((){
      userData = result.data;
     });
  }
```

Since `get()` is asynchronous then use `await` to wait for the result, after that you can call `setState()` which will rebuild the layout with the new data.

---

If you are using `cloud_firestore: 0.14.0+` then use this code:

```
void _onPressed() async{
    var userData;
    var firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    var result = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(firebaseUser.uid).get(); 
    setState((){
      userData = result.data();
     });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since You put this line outside the then function.

```
print('UserData = ${userData}');
```

```dart
firestoreInstance.collection("users").document(firebaseUser.uid).get().then((value){
      setState(){
      userData = value.data
      }
      print('Value data = ${value.data}');
    });
print('UserData = ${userData}'); //Since this line is outside the then function. 

// This line will be execute before the then function(then function will execute after getting the data from firebase)
```